# How to get Twilio Notify to work with firebase FCM

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, twilio

I am following [Twilio firebase quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/quickstart/firebase-web) until point 7, which actually includes the final push notification test, but i am a bit confused on the binding between "identity" and "address". In my understanding the address is just the previously received token so I tried to just register them (didn't use register before to be honest)

```
messaging.getToken()
   .then(function(currentToken) {
      if (currentToken) {
        console.log('Token received: ', currentToken)
        const identity = 'myidentity'
        const address = currentToken
      
        register(identity, address)
      }
   })
```

Unfortunately register expects type "Hooks" and not a string (message is "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Hooks | undefined'.Vetur(2345)")

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The `register` function is actually defined in [the `notify_actions.js` file that is part of the example repo](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/notify-quickstart-webpush/blob/master/notify_actions.js). It looks like:

```js
function register(identity, address){
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/register";
    
    data = {
        'identity': identity,
        'address': address,
        'binding_type': 'fcm'
    }
    postRequest(url, data);
}
```

And `postRequest` is a wrapper around `XMLHttpRequest` to make the request to your server. This is intended to send the identity and address/token first to your server and then on to the Twilio Notify API to register the identity with the device token. You can [see this in the SDK starter back-end](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/sdk-starter-node/blob/master/src/router.js#L30-L37) that the Notify quickstart uses to [create the binding](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/sdk-starter-node/blob/master/src/notification_handler.js#L15-L35).

I'm not sure where your `register` function comes from or why it is giving an error to do with "Hooks", but this is what it should be doing. Hopefully that can help.